# Can Cloudant list/show functions return objects and arrays(any JSON)?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

As per the API documentation for Cloudant: Show function can be used to render a document in a different format or extract only some information from a larger document. Same is the case for a list function, the only difference is that it applies on a set of documents. I created a design document with a show function as follows:

```
{ "shows": { "showDemo":"function(doc,req){return {'body': doc, 'headers':{'Content-Type':'application/json'}}}" } }
```

When I use this function, _design/showFunc/_show/showDemo/doc1, I get the following error:

```
{ "error": "unknown_error", "reason": "badarg", "ref": 1793182837 }
```

I have observed the same error when the show function returns an array. However, no error is given when HTML,Text, XML is returned. Can we say that list/show functions can only return data in a format other than JSON? This example shows the "Accept" header for req object [request Object](https://examples.cloudant.com/docs-examples/_design/couchapp/api/design-documents-get-put-delete-copy.html#request-object).

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the show function needs to return a response object.  From the docs (see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/json-structure.html#response-object) the `body` field needs to be a string, so you can return whatever you like but it needs to be stringified or otherwise turned into a format that can be sent as HTTP.

If you want to send JSON then doing `JSON.Stringify(doc)` as the value for `body` should do what you expect.